# All Python imports stopped working after running a Windows update

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio-code, pip

All my code was running fine until I ran a Windows update and all of my imported libraries such as NumPy and API's like OpenAI are now returning errors.

I already tried:

- restarting again
- rerunning pip installs
- reinstalling python to latest version

errors:

```py
Import "numpy" could not be resolved
Import "openai" could not be resolved
```

details: Python 3.10.10 on win32

Edit: I ran it in windows Powershell and it worked fine. My paths are fine. I think it is a problem with VSCode.

Please help thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Please also read [ask], and try to diagnose the problem. For example, do you know the path to the Python that your code was using before? What was that? What path does VS Code say it will use now? Are you able to run Python from the command line? If you do that, are you able to import those libraries? What exactly was installed in this Windows update? Are you certain that nothing else relevant changed between when the imports worked and now?

Comment: Please keep in mind that this is not a help desk or a discussion forum; we are trying to build a *searchable* Q&A library with questions that can potentially help other people. Among other things, that means that the *exact* causes of the problem need to be *identified*.

Comment: I apoplogize for my lack of knowledge and unclarity. I am not very familiar with PATH but I have made sure to update it through environmental user variables so that it can access my Python files, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: Do you know what `cmd.exe` is? Do you know how to use it to run Python code?

Comment: No I don't, though I think I may have seen that error code. Can you tell me more about it?

Comment: That isn't an error code. It is a program that is on your computer. Do you know what a "command line" is, or a "terminal window"? If not, then there are things that you should learn about *how to use a computer* before trying to learn how to program.

Comment: I apologize, I meant that I've encountered an error statement in the terminal window that mentioned something wasn't recognied as the name of a cmdlet you know what yeah I'm sorry I think I'm going to relearn how to use a computer this is embarrasing I'm so sorry

Comment: Please note that your post is currently omitting important details, please [edit] those in. If you encounter errors, remember to [put those errors in your post](/help/how-to-ask), as people need to know what _specific_ thing you're seeing, based on which _specific_ steps, before they can comment on what might be wrong. Also, please include whether this happens only in VS code, or also when using another terminal (cmd, powershell, etc). If the former, have you tried a clean new install of VS code? If the latter, then VS code is not relevant to the question itself.

Comment: Also, if you were using Python virtual environments (which you probably were, but if you weren't: you should use virtual enironments), did you remember to actually activate those? (And again: make sure to put that information in your post. A future visitor should be able to read it and tell whether or not they're having the same problem. That is not the case right now)

Answer (score 0):

> Import "numpy" could not be resolved
> Import "openai" could not be resolved

This is the reminder provided by intellisense of Pylance or Pylint.

You have to provided the error report after you running the Python file.

According to the reminder, you may choose the correct python interpreter. You can use shortcuts **"Ctrl+Shift+P"** and type **"Python: Select Python Interpreter"** to choose the correct interpreter which contains these two packages.

Answer (score -2):

Try to uninstall a Windows Update.

Go to settings > Windows update > Update History > uninstall updates.

Try this or Check environment variables path.

Comment: If you know that is a good solution, please explain why it works

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).